# How to generate constraint sql?

Tags: postgresql, constraint, scripting

I'm looking for a method that can generate the creating sql, like PgAdmin's `SQL` tab while having selected the constraint. (how pg admin does it?)

I want to implement a generic method that can drop and recreate a foreign key constraint after a process.

Comment: Don't understand why downvoted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgresql has [pg_get_constraintdef](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) function which is for generating a create statement of specific constraint.

Here is an example;

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
create table test (
  id integer primary key,
  data integer check (data between 1 and 100)
);


create table test2 (
  id integer primary key,
  data integer,
  test_id integer references test (id)
);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select
    connamespace::regnamespace "Schema",
    conrelid::regclass "Table",
    conname "Constraint",
    pg_get_constraintdef(oid) "Definition",
    format ('ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD CONSTRAINT %I %s;', 
                connamespace::regnamespace,
                conrelid::regclass,
                conname,
                pg_get_constraintdef(oid)
           )
    
  from pg_constraint 
  where 
    conname IN (
        'test_data_check', 'test_pkey', 
        'test2_pkey', 'test2_test_id_fkey' 
    );
```

| Schema | Table | Constraint | Definition | format |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | test | test_data_check | CHECK (((data >= 1) AND (data <= 100))) | ALTER TABLE public.test ADD CONSTRAINT test_data_check CHECK (((data >= 1) AND (data <= 100))); |
| public | test | test_pkey | PRIMARY KEY (id) | ALTER TABLE public.test ADD CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id); |
| public | test2 | test2_pkey | PRIMARY KEY (id) | ALTER TABLE public.test2 ADD CONSTRAINT test2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id); |
| public | test2 | test2_test_id_fkey | FOREIGN KEY (test_id) REFERENCES test(id) | ALTER TABLE public.test2 ADD CONSTRAINT test2_test_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (test_id) REFERENCES test(id); |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0)